# Configure envoy postgres filter with upstream

Tags: postgresql, envoyproxy

Envoy has a postgres filter that supports ssl termination and ssl origination. I couldn't find any reference online on how to actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it -

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 5432  # Frontend port
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.postgres_proxy
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.postgres_proxy.v3alpha.PostgresProxy
          stat_prefix: imperva
          terminate_ssl: true
          upstream_ssl: REQUIRE
      - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
          stat_prefix: tcp
          cluster: backend_cluster
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.starttls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.starttls.v3.StartTlsConfig
          tls_socket_config:
            common_tls_context:
              tls_certificates:
                certificate_chain:
                  filename: "/etc/envoy/certs/cert.pem"  # Path to SSL certificate
                private_key:
                  filename: "/etc/envoy/certs/key.pem"  # Path to SSL private key
  clusters:
  - name: backend_cluster
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: backend_cluster
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: psql-demo-db.com
                port_value: 5432
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.starttls.v3.UpstreamStartTlsConfig
        tls_socket_config: {}
```